# Clicking on tab always open rootviewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am creating a tabBarApplication in which there is one tab on which camera opens.After clicking on the use tab of the imagepicker I push a new class.
Now my problem is when I again press camera tab that class gets open AND I want that camera should gets opened basically my rootviewcontroller of that tab.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this delegate method, when the selected view controller is camera controller, you can popToRootViewController.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```